# Arrays.fill complexity in java

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

How `Arrays.fill(char[] a,char val)` is implemented **internally** in `java`?

and what is the complexity of it?

Comment: You could [read the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Arrays.java#2950) yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into the definition of `fill(char[] a, char val)` available in `java.util.Arrays` Class.

it is such like this

```
public static void fill(Object[] a, Object val) {
        for (int i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) //this loop will continues to the length of a.
            a[i] = val;
    }
```

So, Complexity for this method would be `O(n)`. where `n` is the length of Object Array `Object[] a` which you passed to the parameter.

Answer (score 7):

The Java implementation uses a simple `for` loop. However, it is important to remember that the JVM often makes significant changes to internal functionality, and often replaces entire methods and classes with lower level implementations at runtime.

Often, depending on the target system, `Arrays.fill` can be replaced with something more like C/C++'s [`memset`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm) function, and as such, it will often run much faster than a regular `for` loop.

In all cases (as described by Vikrant's answer), the complexity should be considered O(N) where N is the total number of elements being set.